# How to format a text file such that it removes blank files and trailing space

Tags: python, text, nlp

[image]I have test.txt that looks like the screenshot

PS: There are trailing spaces in the second line, so it is < space > line 2

in result we have to get:

> line 1
> line 2
> line 3

This is what I have so far

```
with open("test", 'r+') as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
    fd.seek(0)
    fd.writelines(line for line in lines if line.strip())
    fd.truncate()
```

But it is not handling cases when the line starts with space (in the example, line 2) , How do I modify my code? I want to us Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test.txt file:

```
first line

     second line
third line
```

Python Code:

```
#// Imports
import os
#// Global Var's
fileName:str = "test.txt"

#// Logic
def FileCorection(file:str):
    try:
        #// Read original file
        with open(file, "r") as r:
            #// Write a temporary file
            with open(f"temp_{file}", "w") as w:
                # Get line from original file
                line = r.readline()

                # While we still have lines
                while line:
                    # Make a temporary line with out spaces at the end and also at the front of the line (in case they are)
                    tempLine:str = line.strip()
                    #// Check if the line is empty
                    if tempLine == "":
                        Line:tuple = (False, "Empty line...")
                    #// If not then get the line
                    else:
                        Line:tuple = (True, tempLine)

                    #// Print/Show Line if is True... in this case you care set witch line to pre writed in a new file
                    if Line[0] == True:
                        print(Line[1])
                        w.write(f"{Line[1]}\n")

                    line = r.readline()
    finally:
        # Make shore the files are closed
        # By default they shood but just to make shore
        r.close()
        w.close()

        # Now repalce the temp file with the original one
        # By replaceing we delete the original one and we rename the temporary one with the same name
        os.remove(file)
        os.rename(f"temp_{file}", file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FileCorection(fileName)
    # Show when is done
    print(">> DONE!")
```

Console out:

```
first line
second line
third line
>> DONE!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

P.S.: The code was updated/optimized!

Comment: i would also want to update my test.txt with the new format. we will have to write the output in text file. can you help with that as well

Comment: @AayushGupta Done :)

Comment: @AayushGupta I updated the code by removeing useles codes and I add more comments to explain what is mean that line of code :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest formatting the input(screenshot of the text file would do). Assuming your input looks like this you can use strip when text begins with a space.

```
#Code
with open(r"demo.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read()

data_list = [s.strip() for s in data.split("\n") if len(s)>0]
print("\n".join(data_list))
```

Comment: I have added the screenshot as requested